# How to prevent display in task-switcher in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

When you open the task switcher on a Windows phone (Long-press on the Windows button), you can see a preview of all apps wich are currently in "Suspended"-mode. (see Screenshot)
[image: Windows Phone 10 Task switcher]
I guess that windows, like most mobile operating systems, takes a screenshot of the app on suspension to use in the Task switcher.

My app handles sensitive data and I do not want a screenshot with, say, a password on it to be taken automatically.

My idea was to display a blank image that covers the entire screen when `OnSuspending` is called. Unfortunately, at that time, the screenshot is already taken, so that is too late.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Shoot in the dark: Maybe you can try to define a rectangle (example) cover with default opacity equal to 0 (it can be of course image or something else). Then try to change its opacity to 1 in *Page.OnNavigatingFrom* event.

Comment: OnNavigatingFrom is not called on suspension

Comment: Hmm, how you debug your app? Do you use lifecycle tab to test suspending event?

Comment: Yes I did use the LifeCycle tab. I know, the Events are not triggert if you simply press the Windows button while a Debugger is running.

Comment: try this https://www.pedrolamas.com/2014/01/20/disabling-screenshot-functionality-in-a-windows-phone-app/ this will disable screenshots **and** task switcher screenshots.

Comment: smart Idea, but not supported in Windows 10 mobile

Comment: Seems like navigation has changed since 8.1 WinRT in this case. I've tried to play with *Windows.Visibilitychanged*, but it's also fired after the screenshot has been made.

Comment: @GuyMontag are you sure is not supported? look here too https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/c9562480-3211-46e0-a69f-daa851945529/uwpc-isscreencaptureenabled-does-not-work-corerctly?forum=wpdevelop it says it works in windows 10 mobile

Comment: You can disable screen capturing in *ApplicationView*: `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsScreenCaptureEnabled = false;`, but this doesn't help in securing the app - OS still takes a capture once app is suspended.

Answer (score 1):

1. I suppose you are mixing two different things -- how you can prevent user or other app to make a screenshot of your application and how you can prevent OS to "see" your application and to show it to current user.
2. In first case the answer is simple (already mentioned in comments) - use the `IsScreenCaptureEnabled` property to disallow taking screenshots.

Here is example:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Disable screen capture when the user navigates to this page.
    Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsScreenCaptureEnabled = false;
}
```

This is the way how to say to OS that it should protect your app with current page view. From my experience it also works in the task switcher mode -- and prevents me to take screenshot if protected app is present in the list.

3. In the second case -- it is a different story. Such behavior is just part of user experience, there is no difference between showing app in window-mode or in app-switch mode with "screenshot". User should always be able to see owned apps. Not sure why you want to break that behavior -- but ultimately there is no such event when OS says "hey, I'm going to show your app to user in task switcher".

If you have a clear reason to do it, could you please report it thru [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform) or Feedback app?